# Cannot get Animate.css to work with AngularJS 1.3

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

According to several blogs, this should work.

```
<li ng-animate="{enter: 'animated shake'}" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
  <a href="#"> {{name}} </a>
</li>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlp0ckeEWHQcsrzIfAyk?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Since angular 1.2, `ngAnimate` works differently.
See [Matsko's article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html).

To get it working, you ony have to add specific class in your css. Example for `ngIf` directive :

```
.myItem.ng-enter {
  // animation
}

.myItem.ng-leave {
  // animation
}
```

[Read the official docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

For using `Animate.css` with angular >= 1.2, you can read [this article](https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/), [example here](http://jsbin.com/usaruce/3/edit).

```
.my-element.ng-enter {
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.my-element.ng-leave {
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
}
```

Comment: So we can no longer do animation without going into CSS and using AngularJS specific classes?

Comment: Right. The goal was to not use 'presentation based' directives in your html code. It's css job.

Comment: This one is only a css-class toggle based on `ngClick`. `ngAnimate` is used for animating automatically `ngIf`, `ngShow`, `ngRepeat` etc. directives.

Comment: So `ng-animate` is now deprecated. Seems like they've made it harder to integrate third-party animation libs, like animate.css. Not a good decision for non-CSS guys like me.

Comment: Nope! `ngAnimate` still works (and is much better), and you still can use `Animate.css`. Look at the bottom of my answer ! :)

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it seems you don't need the `animated` class, since the animation is referenced in CSS instead. This change still seems like a downgrade to me, since it's no longer possible to stay out of CSS. Just doing `ng-animate="{enter: 'animated shake'}"` seems a lot simpler than having to enter CSS. Not sure why they felt the need to deprecate it.